# SQL Multiple Select Statement

Tags: sql, select, case

I currently I am using select statement to slowly grab the member patronage for different member category at different time interval with 1 of the kiosk system.

```
SELECT COUNT(MemberID) from Member where signin >= '13-10-2013 09:00' and signout <= '13-10-2013 15:00' and MemberType = 1 and kioskid = 1

SELECT COUNT(MemberID) from Member where signin >= '13-10-2013 15:00' and signout <= '13-10-2013 20:00' and MemberType = 1 and kioskid = 1

SELECT COUNT(MemberID) from Member where signin >= '13-10-2013 09:00' and signout <= '13-10-2013 15:00' and MemberType = 2 and kioskid = 1

SELECT COUNT(MemberID) from Member where signin >= '13-10-2013 15:00' and signout <= '13-10-2013 20:00' and MemberType = 2 and kioskid = 1
```

Are there ways for me to grab the data together in one queries as follows:

```
                |  09:00 - 15:00  |  15:00 - 20:00
Premium Member  |       21        |       55
Standard Member |       100       |       300
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do like this:

```
select * from (
select 'Premium Member' mt, a.cnt "9-15", b.cnt "15-20" from 
(SELECT COUNT(MemberID) cnt from Member where signin >= '13-10-2013 09:00' and signout <= '13-10-2013 15:00' and MemberType = 1 and kioskid = 1) a, ( SELECT COUNT(MemberID) cnt from Member where signin >= '13-10-2013 15:00' and signout <= '13-10-2013 20:00' and MemberType = 1 and kioskid = 1) b
union
select 'Standard Member' mt, c.cnt "9-15", d.cnt "15-20" from 
(SELECT COUNT(MemberID) from Member where signin >= '13-10-2013 09:00' and signout <= '13-10-2013 15:00' and MemberType = 2 and kioskid = 1) c, (SELECT COUNT(MemberID) from Member where signin >= '13-10-2013 15:00' and signout <= '13-10-2013 20:00' and MemberType = 2 and kioskid = 1) d
)
```

I have hard coded member types as i dont see any mapping between member type id and member type name in your query. If there exist such mapping then this can be replaced.

Comment: I try your way, but there an error at indicate at the last ")". Can explain what is "mt" and "cnt" for?

Comment: I have some changes to my database to have the a SignIn tables. so it will be like i need to combine the data signin, signout, kioskid from SignIn tables and MemberCategory from Members then union both. How should i code this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use sub-query and group by to do that

```
select MemberType, 
    COUNT(MemberID in (select MemberID 
                       from Member 
                       where signin >= '13-10-2013 09:00' and signout <= '13-10-2013 15:00')),
    COUNT(MemberID (select MemberID 
                    from Member 
                    where signin >= '13-10-2013 15:00' and signout <= '13-10-2013 20:00')) 
from Member 
group by MemberType
```

Comment: You need to bring member type in your main query else group by wil fail.

Comment: The query won't fail without MemberType since main query can query entire Member table. But I realized that without MemberType, you won't know which count number belongs to which MemberType. Made edit to reflect that.